# HOWTO use tikz to generate diagram to show organization of big proof (non-terminal nodes are lemmas, and other auxiliary propositions)

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, flow-charts

How to generate the following diagram (see page 4 of this document https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.13661.pdf).

[image]

Notice that the text in red are actually clickable links. Also, ideally I'd like the solution to be as position-independent as possible (i.e not many, if any, hard-coded coordinates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
  start chain = going below,
   arr/.style = {{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}-, rounded corners=1ex, semithick},
     N/.style = {draw, rounded corners, thick, fill=#1,
                 text width=8em, align=center, inner ysep=2ex},
   N/.default = white,
every edge/.style = {draw, arr}
                        ]   
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain,join=by arr}]
\node[N=red!30] {Theorem 1};            % Theorem \ref{t:1}
\node[N=orange!30] {Lemma 1};
\node (n11) [N=orange!30] {Lemma 2};
    \end{scope}
%
\node (n21) [N=blue!30, right=of n11]  {Lemma 4};
\node (n22) [N=blue!30, above=of n21]  {Lemma 3};
\node (n23) [N=blue!30, below=of n21]  {Lemma 5};
%
\node (n31) [N, right=of n23]  {Lemma 6};
\node (n32) [N, above=of n31]  {Lemma 7};
\node (n33) [N, below=of n31]  {Lemma 8};
%
\node (n41) [N, right=of n32]  {Lemma 10};
\node (n42) [N, above=of n41]  {Lemma 9};
\node (n43) [N, below=of n41]  {Lemma 11};
% connections
\draw[arr]  (n11)-- (n21);
\draw[arr]  ([yshift=+1ex] n11.east) -- ++ (0.4,0) |- (n22);
\draw[arr]  ([yshift=-1ex] n11.east) -- ++ (0.4,0) |- (n23);
% 
\draw[arr]  (n23)-- (n31);
\draw[arr]  ([yshift=+1ex] n23.east) -- ++ (0.4,0) |- (n32.west);
\draw[arr]  ([yshift=-1ex] n23.east) -- ++ (0.4,0) |- (n33.west);
%
\draw[arr]  (n32)-- (n41);
\draw[arr]  ([yshift=+1ex] n32.east) -- ++ (0.4,0) |- (n42.west);
\draw[arr]  ([yshift=-1ex] n32.east) -- ++ (0.4,0) |- (n43.west);
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks!